# Excess minority carrier concentrations at the edges of the depletion layer

Tags: diodes, pn-junction

In a pn juction how do the excess minority carrier concentrations at the edges of the depletion layer p'(xn ),n'(−xp ) depend on the forward-bias voltage? Are these the maximum concentrations of the minority electrons and holes, respectively.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. But here is a stab at it.
When a bias voltage is set up across a PN junction, the electric field acts on the charge carriers within the P and N type materials. Electrons move in one direction (counter to the field) while holes move in the opposite direction (with the field). This sets up you carrier differential across the PN junction. The stronger the field, the more carriers are affected. If the bias is reversed, then the charge carrier arrangement is reversed. Is that helpful?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

At the edge of the space charge region, the minority carriers are at their maximum and as they diffuse into and recombine there will be an decay of concentration.  Which contributes to band bending (from their contributions to the fermi level).